# How to get the value from AngularFireObject<Object>

Tags: angular

I am learning Angular, creating basic app where i got stuck while performing db operation.

I have service to get the user from database as below

```
getUser(uid : String) : AngularFireObject<AppUser> {
    return this.db.object('/users/'+uid);
  }
```

I am calling above function from canActivate method where i need to get the user and return the property(return user.isAdmin, boolean property ) of user object. so i added below code

```
 canActivate() :  Observable<boolean>{
    return this.auth.user$.map(user =>  this.userService.getUser(user.uid)).map( appUser => appUser.isAdmin);
  }
```

In above code, i am unable to call appUser.isAdmin. can you pls help me to return isAdmin property from canActivate method . Following error is thrown

```
Property 'isAdmin' does not exist on type 'AngularFireObject<AppUser>
```

Suggest a better solution please

Comment: Please tag with the actual framework you're using. `angularjs` is the tag for the AngularJS 1.x framework. `angular` is for the Angular 2+ framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `appUser.isAdmin` because `appUser` is not of `AppUser` type where I'm assuming the `isAdmin` is a property of. According to this function,

```
getUser(uid : String) : AngularFireObject<AppUser> {
    return this.db.object('/users/'+uid);
  }
```

the return type is `AngularFireObject`. Please, follow Josie's solution to return an observable that would give you `AppUser` object on subscription.

Answer (score 0):

After reading some of the AngularFire [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) I think you need to turn your

```
getUser(uid : String) : AngularFireObject<AppUser> {
    return this.db.object('/users/'+uid);
  }
```

into

```
getUser(uid : String) : Observable<AppUser> {
    return this.db.object('/users/'+uid).valueChanges();
  }
```

And then you would subscribe to the observable as normal.

Comment: thanks for your help !!.. u have said returning valuechanges...but valuechanges method returns Observable< {}> not Observable<AppUser>

Comment: Did you try subscribing after the above code changes?  It would look something like this 

`canActivate() :  boolean{
    this.auth.user$.map(user =>  this.userService.getUser(user.uid)).subscribe(appUser => {
     return appUser.isAdmin;
});
  }`

Or are you saying you've done the above and it's returning an empty object?

Comment: Or, you could save the return object in whatever component calls getUser().  Something like 

`var user: AppUser;` 

And then in `ngOnInit() { this.auth.user$.map(user =>  this.userService.getUser(user.uid)).subscribe( appUser => {this.user = appUser});`

Then you can just check the property `user.isAdmin`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
getUser(uid : String) : AngularFireObject<AppUser> {
  return this.db.object('/users/'+uid);
}
```

to

```
get(uid:string):Observable<any> {
  return this.db.object('/users/'+uid).valueChanges();
}
```

and

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.auth.user$.map(user =>  this.userService.getUser(user.uid)).map(appUser => appUser.isAdmin);
}
```

to

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.auth.user$
    .pipe(switchMap((user) => this.userService.get(user.uid)))
    .pipe(
      map((appUser) => {
        return appUser.isAdmin;
      })
    );
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The code snippets you provided might be of some immediate, limited help. However, a [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve your answer's long-term value by showing why it is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with similar questions. 
Please edit your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: please indent your code